# svn error: svn: Can't close file 'weighted_decision/.svn/tmp/entries': Input/output error

Tags: svn

When I try to update (or commit out) svn, I find the following error:

svn: Can't close file 'weighted_decision/.svn/tmp/entries': Input/output error

I have no clue about what is happing. Does anyone know the reason? Thank you very much, it will help me a lot!!!!

Best,

Qiang

Answer (score 5):

This means that you do not have enough disk space to do the update/checkout.